# Repeat Alarm Manager At Exact Interval in API=>19?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intervals

I had a massive reading and still I think there is not a clear/complete Answer to this question.

First some stuff to clarify :
this question is not concern with battery saving on phone but more about precise timing and I Am a newbie in Android.

Now let me explain the question in more depth. I have a Alarm manager that will invoke a toast (for simplicity) on given interval (every 2 minutes) `manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);`
 
The above will invoke a onReceive() methode on a BroadcastReciver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast ....bala blah
   }}
```

Now This was exact interval on API<19 however In API=>19  setRepeating() is not exact anymore ! I found some people suggested (on the other forms) to use setExact(). but there is no example or clear explanation on how to use setExact() in Interval (or I could not find that). As far as I understood setExact() is on off action unlike setRepeating() so according to some others next schedule needs to be set through onReceive() (again I could not find  an example ;( . Anyhow this is where I am now . And I really Appreciate any comment or suggestion or link or example ...

I hope I asked my question clear enough, by the way if there is another approach to this (for running a task on precise intervals in API>19 please let me know too) Many thanks

Comment: check this indirect [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795873/android-show-a-dialog-when-the-internet-gps-loses-connectivity-or-is-not-connect/27796949#27796949) or the direct [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570024/repeat-service-task/25570326#25570326) in response to another approach

Comment: not exact any more. damn thats a problem fro me as iam making an alarm app

Answer (score 9):

You can use `setExact` similarly to `setRepeating`.

```
void scheduleAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent yourIntent = new Intent();
    //TODO configure your intent
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, MyApplication.ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, yourIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToWakeUp, alarmIntent);
}
```

The two differences are:

1. The timing will be exact (or [as nearly as possible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)))
2. You will have to schedule the next occurrence in the `onReceive` of your BroadcastReceiver.

   ```
     public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //TODO process alarm
       scheduleAlarm(context);
     }}
   ```

Comment: but do I need to make minSDKversion = 19 in order to use setExact?

Comment: @MrNarendra No you do not need to do that.

Comment: what if the alarm does not start for any reason like power off etc ... in this case next alarm not scheduled?